# Cropped image is blurred in TouchImageView

Tags: android, android-studio, imageview, android-crop

I used crop intent to add image cropping functionality to my application. I used [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) as my image view. After cropping and setting the cropped image to the TouchImageView, the image is blurred. Before adding this crop functionality, I have done this to get the image data from camera and set it to TouchImageView as:

```
        Uri imageUri;
        TouchImageView myTVF = (TouchImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
        imageUri = data.getData();
        myTVF.setImageURI(imageUri);
```

But now, in order to use crop intent, after image capture followed by cropping, I am using this to set the cropped image to my TouchImageView:

```
           (....)
            else if(requestCode == PIC_CROP){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap thePic= extras.getParcelable("data");
            myTVF.setImageBitmap(thePic);
```

But, the image set is now blurry. Can anyone help me with this? (I am also trying to use other available cropping libraries.. but I just wanted to know why this is not working)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you were calling `startActivity()` on an `Intent` with an action of `com.android.camera.action.CROP`.

There is [article saying that android doesn't not have crop intent](https://commonsware.com/blog/2013/01/23/no-android-does-not-have-crop-intent.html). So I recommend to use [another good 3rd party library.](https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop)

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have tried using that library but I was not able to follow his steps! Can you help me with it? Where should I include this line? : Crop.of(inputUri, outputUri).asSquare().start(activity). I want to crop the image as soon as I capture image from camera in my app.

Comment: @ShravanDG You can call it after crop finish. Usually I catch inside `protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)`, check the resultCode with `if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == Crop.REQUEST_PICK)`. There ya go, you can put `Crop.of(inputUri, outputUri).asSquare().start(activity)` there.